# Como puedo recibir el file en mi archivo?

Tags: php, ajax, fileupload

Tengo la siguiente función que manda un archivo de Excel a un controlador 
pero el problema es que no logro que lo reciba.

La función es la siguiente:

```
function Articuloconexcel(){
var file = $('#files')[0].files[0]
var data = new FormData();
  data.append('archivo',file);
  var url = 'WEB-INF/Controllers/Aceptacion/Controler_excel.php';
 $.ajax
({  
    url:url,
    type:'POST',
    contentType:false,
    data:data,
    processData:false,
    cache:false
   });
}
```

Intenté recibir el archivo de la siguiente forma:

```
<?php       
$archivo = $_FILES['excel']['name'];
$tipo = $_FILES['excel']['type'];
$destino = "cop_".$archivo;//Le agregamos un prefijo para identificarlo el archivo cargado
if (copy($_FILES['excel']['tmp_name'],$destino)) echo "Archivo Cargado Con Éxito";
else echo "Error Al Cargar el Archivo";
```

Pero solo me arroja el mensaje de error ¿como podría hacer para que reciba bien el archivo?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No tienes que usar destino, tienes que usar la función **move_file_upload** indicando el origen y destino. Solo de este modo podrás trabajar con el fichero de Excel.

Te quedaría:

```
<?php       
$ruta_destino = 'cop_'.$archivo;
$fichero_final = $ruta_destino . basename($_FILES["excel"]["name"]);
$tipo_fichero = pathinfo($fichero_final,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["filepath"]["tmp_name"], $fichero_final)){
     echo "Archivo cargado con éxito";
}else{
     echo "Error al cargar el archivo";
}
```

Más info en la documentación: [Move_upload_file](https://www.php.net/move_uploaded_file)

Comment: gracias me sirvió mucho